# How do I use cookies with Foreach

Tags: php, cookies, foreach

I adopted code given in this code:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp
and
[How do I use cookies to store users' recent site history(PHP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813659/how-do-i-use-cookies-to-store-users-recent-site-historyphp)

and i changed the code with the link above

Example: user clicks on url

```
file.php?id=200&value=woman
file.php?id=150&value=woman
file.php?id=250&value=girl
```

and this code is here:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$value = $_GET['value'];
$cookie_id = $id;
$cookie_value = $value ;
setcookie($cookie_id, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_id])) {
    foreach ($_COOKIE[$cookie_id] as $cookie_id => $value) { 
        echo 'id: '.$cookie_id.' '; echo ', value: '.$cookie_id.' <br>'; 
    }
} else {
    echo 'Cookie named '.$cookie_id.' is not set!';
}
```

Out: the output of the code above should be as follows

```
id: 200, value: woman
id: 150, value: woman
id: 250, value: girl
```

Error: this error shows me this way.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/cookie.php on line 7
```

and also I found this code [Foreach loop with cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887989/foreach-loop-with-cookies) , but failed:

What could be the reason and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of $_COOKIE[$cookie_id]. I think it's not an array and so that's why foreach cannot iterate over it.

Comment: Remove `[$cookie_id]` from `$_COOKIE[$cookie_id]`. Don't name `index` in `foreach loop` as prev variable name - *$cookie_id*. Name it `as $ind=>$val`. For debugging make `print_r($_COOKIE);` before `loop` and you'll see with what you can work further.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the result of `print_r($_COOKIE)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **[$cookie_id]** from **$_COOKIE[$cookie_id]**. Don't name index in **foreach loop** as prev variable name - **$cookie_id**. Name it as **$ind=>$val**. For debugging make **print_r($_COOKIE);** before loop and you'll see with what you can work further.